# CoreData Background Thread Update Has Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have a random bug that has plagued me for months that I simply can't figure out. I would say that it fails fewer than 1 in a 1000 times. I must have CoreData configured incorrectly but I can't figure out or recreate it. The basic gist is that I receive some information from the server and I am then updating a CoreData object in a background thread. The CoreData object is not immediately needed for the UI.

All of this is performed in DataService which has a reference to the NSManagedObjectContext that was originally created in the AppDelegate. Note: Anything that references [DataService sharedService] uses the AppDelegate.NSManagedObjectContext:

```
@interface DataService : NSObject {}
  @property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@end
```

When the server returns with data the updateProduct method is called:

```
@implementation DataService

  + (NSManagedObjectContext*) newObjectContext
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];           //step 1

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];               
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext observeContext:context];

    return context;
  }

  +(void) saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*) context
  {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
      if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        // Handle Error
      }
    }
  }

  +(void) updateProduct: (Product*) product
  {
    if(product == nil)
      return;

    //run in background
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void){

      //create private managed object
      NSManagedObjectContext *context = [DataService newObjectContext];

      CoreDataProduct* coreProduct = [DataService product:product.productId withObjectContext:context];
      if(product != nil)
      {
        //copy data over from product
        coreProduct.text = product.text;

        //ERROR HAPPENS HERE on save changes
        [DataService saveContext:context];
      }

    //remove background context listening from main thread
    [DataService.managedObjectContext stopObservingContext:context];

});
  }

@end
```

I use the general NSManagedObjectContext+Helper.h category file that is floating around GitHub and my EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error happens in the [DataService.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromNotification:(NSNotification *)notification] method which calls this

```
@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (Helper)

  - (void) mergeChangesFromNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
    //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    [self mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
  }

@end
```

I cannot figure out why the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification method fails randomly. I think that the error is due to losing reference to the original shared managedObjectContext. Although if that were true, I guess I would expect the error to be in the updateProduct method and not in the category class.

I suppose that both the newObjectContext and the stopObservingContext methods reference the managedObjectContext on the background thread from the main thread. Since I'm creating a private managedObjectContext, do I even need to make the main thread shared context aware of the private context? If so, am I doing it incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe you should show the failing method, `mergeChanges...`.

Comment: The last item in the stack trace is -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] which I don't think gives a lot of information.

Comment: Perhaps you should not use GCD but the context concurrency APIs such as `performBlock`. Also, put a breakpoint at the line and examine the notification.

Comment: Marcus Zarra in his book (from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013)) presents an interesting mechanism to provide a robust framework for parent child contexts that I find rock solid. If you're not committed to older iOS this might be worth investigating.

Comment: Also I am interested as to why you create a new context in your method `newObjectContext`. Do you not already have a context you can reference and relate to?

Comment: Actually the comment by Mundi using `performBlock` (or `performBlockAndWait`) is aligned with the Zarra mechanism.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Thanks for the book suggestion, I may have to buy that. My understanding is that you're not supposed to retrieve data from an objectContext across different threads. Each thread gets it's own context. I'm obviously violating this rule which I'm hoping is my actual problem. My biggest setback is because this can't be reproduced locally, I'll have to deploy and update and see if the bug goes away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears because the new NSManagedObjectContext was being created on the background thread, the original/parent NSManagedObjectContext needed to be observed on the main thread. Once I changed observeContext to observeContextOnMainThread, this CoreData problem seems to have gone away. I hope this helps someone.

Here's my updated method:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext*) newObjectContext
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];           //step 1

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];               
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext observeContextOnMainThread:context];

    return context;
  }
```